# Why is the git on my system when I never installed it?

Tags: 16.04, git

So on my Ubuntu system I have the git version 2.7.4.

However, I remember I had never installed git. Should I update the current git version on my system to the latest version?

Ubuntu: 16.04 LTS
OS Type: 64-bit

Comment: What is the question, 1) Should I update or 2) Why is git on my system?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen These questions are linked. Because I wanted the latest version of git, that I checked if it was already there. I found the git version 2.7.4 already installed. I never installed it. And the question it should I update this version to the latest one?

Comment: @Melebius linuxbrew-wrapper  depends upon git. or maybe this version of git.

Comment: Yes, Linuxbrew is built on Git. The Git version 2.7.4 is the latest for 16.04 (see https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/git). For why it does not get upgraded in the repository, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software.

Comment: @Melebius Thanks for the links. The ask Ubuntu link clears everything. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

1. > Why is git on my system?

   If you’re sure you didn't install it then a program you installed needs it to work.
2. > Should I update it?

   Well if running `sudo apt update` updates it, then fine else if you’re trying to update that instance only, better find which program installed it first and be sure a newer version is ok. Check that with `apt-cache depends git | less`.

Comment: I like to use `aptitude`, `aptitude why git`...

Comment: I like aptitude for its attitude but still use to vanilla.